# How to fix 401 error in listing users after Firebase update to 8.2.0

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm creating an app that lists users and I'm doing that through Firebase Functions. After a recent update I've been forced to update firebase-admin from 7.4.0 to 8.2.0 but now I'm getting the following error:

> Unhandled error { Error: //developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. Raw server response: "{"error":{"code":401,"message":"Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.","errors":[{"message":"Invalid Credentials","domain":"global","reason":"authError","location":"Authorization","locationType":"header"}],"status":"UNAUTHENTICATED"}}"

I've already done the following:

- Use service account
- Follow instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#before_you_begin) but I'm still seeing the errors above.

Edit: Here's the code

```
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import functions from "firebase-functions";

const app = admin.initializeApp();
const auth = admin.auth(app);

export const listUsers = functions.https.onCall(async () => {
  const users = await auth.listUsers();

  return users.users.map(user => {
    return user.toJSON();
  });
});
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that's not working the way you expect.

Comment: Try importing `firebase-functions` before `firebase-admin`.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka tried it just now and i'm getting the same errors.

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? If it's happening in the production Functions environment you should probably reach out to Firebase support. If it's in local testing, I'd say make sure your Firbase CLI is authenticated properly.